# C++ overriden functions in loops

Tags: c++, oop, vector

Alright, I'm trying to call a function from a class in C++ what overides a function from its parent class.

The class is setup:

`BaseClass` that has the update function declared publicly like this:

```
virtual void update() = 0;
```

Then I have the `Object` class what extends the `BaseClass`. In this class I declare update again by doing:

```
virtual void update() override;
```

Then I have my `Player` class what has its update function declared like this:

```
void update() override;
```

I then store a vector of object and loop through it the vector is declared:

```
std::vector<Object> _objs
```

Do I have to create a new vector to loop through to call the right update function or is there some sort of way I can call the *right* update function when im looping through a array of object?

Comment: Instead of describing the class setup, why don't you just show us some code?

Comment: One line of code explains more than hundred lines of prose in most cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a vector of instances of different subclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338548/making-a-vector-of-instances-of-different-subclasses)

Comment: It will automatically call the correct override function. That's what overrides are for.

Comment: @QuentinUK No it won't, because of slicing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Biffen That can be fixed by using a vector of pointers std::vector<Object> _objs should be std::vector<Object*> _objs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either a vector of pointers

```
std::vector<Object*>
```

or smart pointers

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>
```

If you don't, adding a `Player` object to the vector will result in object slicing. `Player` will be converted to `Object`, so `Object`'s implementation of `update()` will be called instead.

Comment: `update` is not pure virtual in `Object`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl My bad, I fixed the answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!