# creating a class vector that contains subclass

Tags: c++, visual-studio, subclass, declaration, stdvector

I have a vector that I would like to store subclasses in. The problem I am facing though is that it is giving me an error. 
I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338548/making-a-vector-of-instances-of-different-subclasses) as a reference but now I am getting this error:

> Error: "Subclass::Subclass" (declared at...) is inaccessible.

My code is as follows:

```
class SuperClass
{
 public:
    SuperClass() {}
    ~SuperClass() {}

};
class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
   SubClass() {} //there is no .cpp
   ~SubClass() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<SuperClass*> superClass;
    superClass.push_back(new SubClass());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a **complete but minimal** example that readers can try.

Comment: That said, the compiler's diagnostic "is inaccessible" says it all. The constructor is inaccessible because members of a `class` are `private` by default. So either use the `struct` keyword or, better here, add `public:` access specifier before the constructor definition, or, ungood, make class `Program` a `friend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default access type for `class` is `private`. Hence, both the constructor and the destructor of `Subclass` are `private`. Add the `public` access specifier before them.

```
class Subclass : public SuperClass{

     // Add this
     public:

        SubClass() {} //there is no .cpp
       ~SubClass() {}
  };
```

Comment: It worked. Well done, I just forgot the access type.